# How is Swift resolving this at compile time?

Tags: ios, swift, subclass

This is my second day coding in Swift, so I'm very new. I got the following piece of code online that enumerates audio/video devices on an iOS device using an Apple API:

```
let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

// Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
for device in devices {

    // Make sure this particular device supports video
    if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now if I look up what `AVCaptureDevice.devices()` returns, I find this in Apple documentation:

```
class func devices() -> [AnyObject]!
```

So surely this would mean that device is of type `AnyObject` (a very generic type) and the highly specialized call `device.hasMediaType`(...) which I guess must be implemented in some more specialized subclass should not be possible. I would expect an error that `AnyObject` does not have a function called `hasMediaType` (I'm pretty sure it doesn't).

So why is this working? Even the auto-complete seems to offer me the `hasMediaType()` function in the editor. My understanding is that this should not be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AnyObject` means that all known Objective-C methods and properties are available (see [here](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.0/protocol/AnyObject/)).

You'll notice that *everything* is offered as an autocomplete. It's an equivalent to using `id` in Objective-C.

If you use a method that isn't implemented by `AVCaptureDevice`, you'll still get autocompletion, but you will crash at runtime.

Apple are gradually replacing all of these with typed arrays where possible, so this ambiguity will be removed eventually.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at what is `AnyObject`,you will find document like this

```
@objc protocol AnyObject
```

> The protocol to which all classes implicitly conform. When used as a
>   concrete type, **all known @objc methods and properties are available**,
>   as implicitly-unwrapped-optional methods and properties respectively,
>   on each instance of AnyObject.

For example

```
class A:NSObject{
    func a_test(){

    }
}
```

Then you call

```
  var b:AnyObject?;
  b?.a_test();
```

> This is OK in XCode,just be compiled to send message to object b,but will crash at runtime

Because,any Object is `id` in Objective C,and it is about "Sending message to a object",it will be solved by **Objective C runtime**